# func :: Maybe(Int) -> Maybe(Int)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, option-type

I've done some research but couldn't find anything. I don't understand how a function like this works:

```
func :: Maybe (Int) -> Maybe (Int)
```

How am I supposed to do the pattern matching? I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
func Just a  = Just a | otherwise = Nothing
func Nothing = Just Nothing | otherwise = Nothing
```

How can I make this work?

Error message:

> ```
> exercises6.hs:83:22: error: parse error on input ‘|’
>    |
> 83 | func Just a = Just a | otherwise = Nothing
>    |                      ^
> ```

Comment: There are a number of mistakes here (don't worry, we all make them, especially when first learning). I'm curious what you were trying to achieve here with the `| otherwise = Nothing` though.

Comment: Seconded. I made this exact mistake with guards. You'll get it.

Answer (score 8):

You pattern match on the two possible cases. A `Maybe a` has two data constructors: a `Nothing`, and a `Just …` with `…` the value it wraps. There is no `| otherwise` part when you do pattern matching. The pipe character (`|`) is used for [*guards* [lyah]](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards).

So you can for example increment the value in a `Just` with:

```
func :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
func (Just x) = Just (x+1)
func Nothing = Nothing
```

The brackets around `Just x` are required here, as [@chepner says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58827732/func-maybeint-maybeint-haskell/58827755?noredirect=1#comment103932055_58827755). Otherwise it will be parsed as if `Just` is the first parameter, and `x` is a second parameter.

Since `Maybe` is an instance of the [**`Functor`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Functor), you can make use of [**`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) here:

```
func :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
func = fmap (1+)
```

Comment: Also, note the parentheses around `(Just x)` are required; otherwise, `func Just x = ...` would interpreted as matching against the literal argument `Just` and an irrefutable pattern `x` matching any second argument.

Comment: May be useful to say that the separator between equations is a semicolon `;`, not a `|`. `func (Just x) = Just (x + 1); func Nothing = Nothing`. Putting the equations on separate lines inserts a virtual semicolon via layout. `|` is for *guards*.